# Update an embedded document with $set

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-update, embedded-documents

I have a document in this form

```
{
   "firstName": "John",
   "lastName": "Doe",
   "preferences": {
      "xxx": true,
      "yyy": false,
      "zzz": true
   }
}
```

I want to update specific fields in the `preferences` embedded document. If I use the `$set` operand in the following way

```
db.users.update({name: "John"}, {$set: {preferences: {"xxx": false}}})
```

the `preferences` document is completely replaced, so I get this

```
{
   "firstName": "John",
   "lastName": "Doe",
   "preferences": {
      "xxx": false
   }
}
```

while I would like to obtain this

```
{
   "firstName": "John",
   "lastName": "Doe",
   "preferences": {
      "xxx": false,
      "yyy": false,
      "zzz": true
   }
}
```

I cannot use:

```
db.users.update({name: "John"}, {$set: {"preferences.xxx": false}})
```

because I don't know which specific field I'm going to update, I only have as input an object that may or may not contain each field of the `preferences` document.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating the update object prior to the update. For instance, if you have as input the object `{"xxx": false, "abc": false}`, you could use JavaScript's **[bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)** to create the update object as follows:

```
var input = {"xxx": false, "abc": false},
        update = { "$set": {} },
        keys = Object.keys(input),
        query = {"name": "John"};
keys.forEach(function(key){ update["$set"]["preference."+key] = input[key]; });
printjson(update); // {"$set":{"preference.xxx":false,"preference.abc":false}} 


db.users.update(query, update);
```